# Android Serial Connection

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, usb, uart

I looked around and I have a hard time finding an answer to my question. We have an app written with Xamarin. I see SerialPort class being exposed. Not sure what it means in terms of Android. We will be using this application with custom made tablets in our device. We can have usb 3.0s but our hardware team would like to implement UART or RS 232 ports instead. We have a microcontroller which will communiucate with our tablet. Is this even possible or are we stuck witb adding a usb/serial converter in the middle. Thanks for the insight

Comment: Have you seen a physical UART/RS232 port on the device? If so, why not connect it up and have a go with that class? Note the port names might look like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11194427/360211

Comment: Issue is the tablets need to be built. They are asking for a definite answer before doing that. They are contracting out the tablets to a 3rd party vendor. Not sure if they are willing to just make one. As of now I am dead set and having a converter in the middle. Adds a bit to the cost but no more than 10 bucks when high volume is ordred

Comment: Also thanks for the link. I have gone over most of the articles. In theory this should work. Well. Hopefully