# Communicate android through arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

Could anyone plz tell me how to communticate android through arduino.Like we know ,we can send any char from android to arduino.But my idea is to transfer any char from serial monitor of arduino to android.is that possible.?

Answer (score 0):

Android does have provisions for interfacing with USB devices, for that you need to set up your device as [USB HOST](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

For more information you can see the explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11194427/14002303